# Rstudio unable to install package devtools: gcc error

Tags: gcc, installation, rstudio, devtools

I want to install package devtools. But after successful downloading of all dependencies, it gives error while installing of the form:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c rawmatch.c -o rawmatch.o
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fstack-protector-strong’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wdate-time’
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:159: recipe for target 'rawmatch.o' failed
make: *** [rawmatch.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mime’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/mime’
```

I have checked `gcc`. I am able to run a sample c program file from terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you'll need to use a more recent gcc version, 4.9 at least.

Both unrecognized options, `-fstack-protector-strong` and `-Wdate-time`, were introduced in gcc 4.9 ([release notes](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/gcc-4.9/changes.html)).